# Record showing twice in sql query while comparing 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 table,employee table and salary process table. Once I processed salary corresponding employee detail, I insert into salary process table.

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT
    employee_tbl.emp_maxid,
    emp_name AS 'Employee Name',
    Designation_tbl.Des_Name AS Designation,
    emp_LabourID,
    emp_IBAN,
    emp_monthlysalary AS Salary,
    0 AS commission,
    emp_monthlysalary  AS Total,
    --ISNULL(s.Salary - sum(S.Paid), emp_monthlysalary) AS Total,
    isnull(s.balance,0) as balance
FROM 
    dbo.employee_tbl
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Designation_tbl ON Designation_tbl.Des_id = employee_tbl.Des_id
LEFT JOIN 
    SalaryProcessLog_tbl S ON S.emp_maxid = employee_tbl.emp_maxid
WHERE 
    (emp_deleted = 0
     OR emp_deleted IS NULL)
    AND employee_tbl.emp_maxid NOT IN (SELECT emp_maxid
                                       FROM SalaryProcessLog_tbl 
                                       WHERE CAST(SalaryMnth AS DATE) = '2018-04-26')
GROUP BY 
    employee_tbl.emp_maxid, dbo.employee_tbl.emp_name, Designation_tbl.Des_Name,
    employee_tbl.emp_LabourID, emp_IBAN,emp_monthlysalary, 
    s.Salary, s.balance
```

My output is like this:

[image]

In output, the record for `jaseem` is showing up twice, but in my `SalaryProcessLog_tbl`, that record only exists in one particular month.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Which column holds the date you want to filter?

Comment: That would be so much more readable with table alias.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci please see edited question

Comment: @paparazzo please see edited question

Comment: You are grouping by balance so of course you get multiple rows. The real problem here is that we can't see your screen and have no idea what you table structure is like or what you are trying to do. In fact, your question has completely taken a different direction now. You need to give us some information.  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @user3262364 I don't see any new table alias.  I cannot speak for others but I skip on questions that don't take the effort to be readable.

Comment: And please be consistent with your queries. You have some columns not referencing the table (bad habit) and others do. Using aliases and some formatting will make your code so much easier to work with. Not just for us for you as well. Show some pride in your work and make it look nice.